# Escape Regex Newline

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ascii

How would I make a \n match in regex? I want the actual two ASCII values 92 and 110 to be matched (as a string).

I'm using preg from PHP
Thanks

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 10):

You can either escape the first slash: `\\n`

Or wrap the first slash in []: `[\]n`

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to match a real linebreak but a string (with two characters) like `'\n'` then you just have to escape the backslash with another one `\\n` so that it will not be recognized as linebreak.

But most programming languages are a bit different when it comes to escaping, so you have to check your language docs for that, but two backslashes will probably work.