# PHP - strspn($input, $allowed_chars) can not seem to be able to work with "\r\n"

Tags: php

i have a textarea box

```
<textarea>abc
d</textarea>
```

i post this to the php script.

in php script i have..:

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
$allowed_chars= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .<>="';
$scan = strspn($a, $allowed_chars);
if ($scan < strlen($a)){
echo "not allowed char after the $scan : ". substr($a, $scan,1)
}
```

this will print this on the web browser:

```
  not allowed char after the 3 :
```

obviously the new line is a problem.

i want to know what i can add to my

```
  $allowed_chars
```

list. i tried adding

```
\\
```

( escaped forward? backward? slash )

it did not work.

after the

```
  not allowed char after the 3 :
```

it is suppose to tell me the character causing the problem but it is simply empty.. showing nothing. how can it be designed so it can show the conflicting character ?

**UPDATE**

this does not work

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
$allowed_chars= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .<>="\r\n';
$scan = strspn($a, $allowed_chars);
if ($scan < strlen($a)){
echo "not allowed char after the $scan : ". substr($a, $scan,1)
}
```

( added \r\n to the list )

**update 2**

this also does not work:

```
$allowed_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "\r\n"';
```

**update 3**
solution seems to be to first use php's nl2br() function on the "$input".

Comment: `\r\n` to allow both new line symbols

Comment: my "allowed_chars" will see "\r\n" as "4" characters. it does not work.

Comment: allowed_chars will see `\r\n` as 2 symbols, because php will convert them

Comment: use double quotes around allowed chars, instead of single one

Comment: or use `$allowed_chars .= "\r\n";`

Comment: `$allowed_chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 \"\r\n";`

Comment: perhaps if it could print the conflicting character.. i could go on from there. but how do i make it print it ? do i convert it into ascii first or something ?

Comment: i suspect my $allowed_chars list is being scanned character by character and thus .. \r\n are irrelavant. but also.. i think i first need to get it to show me the character causing the conflict. which character comes right after 3rd character ? if the new lines are \n then i suppose it would have to be "\" ?

Comment: why can i not get it to print out the character that is the 4th character in the "$a" variable ?

Comment: I've already posted correct allowed_chars initialization, find the differences between your incorrect variants, then study any book about php syntax. Also it makes sense to figure out "what" symbol should be printed for invisible new line char?

Comment: well anyway this question kind of went to trash. there was no regex in my codes. i do not know why such assumptions rained. i can not use "\n" in my code because it is a character by character scan.

Comment: try what I posted before and you will see that it works as you expected

Comment: you see i do not want to use regex because regex is slow. this code does not work with \n\r because it scans characters 1 by 1.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you regexps, you just made several typos in your initialization

Comment: \r\n - are 2 (two) symbols, not 4 (four) and they are not regexp

Comment: it is best to put this question to sleep permanently. i tried deleting it but due to answers having been posted.. could not delete it. my apologies for failing the world. i tried dear world.. ( deleting it ).. please forgive me as these texts might linger around on the Internet for the next 30 years or maybe who knows.. much more ? i am so sorry.

Comment: dear planet earth. the notice reads "please avoid extended discussions". i could not comply. i failed you planet earth. i am so sorry. too many comments were posted and thus the question has to be abandoned because everything simply looks bad. it should have been solved with very little discussion in the comments section. did not work out. i am so sorry world. i will later try posting this question in 2-3 segments until i find a clear resolution.

Comment: have you tried what I posted? have you really copy-pasted my comment (not typed it wrongly, but copy-pasted)?

Comment: it does not matter any more. even if there is an answer.. it does not matter any more. discussion was too extended via comments. everything looks very unprofessional. companies will no longer bother hiring anybody that they see here. everything got ruined. everything went to garbage.

Answer (score 0):

in that post 
[Escape Regex Newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842404/regex-newline-match)
you can see that to make a new line char is : '\n'
so for regexp could be '\n'
and then you can add as \ as you tell before
expect help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that new line are multiple characters that define a distinct character. While you state *\r\n* that means you're on Windows and this code will also not work on a Linux server.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but from the code I see its better to use Regex.

```
$s = 'some string I want to see the data on.';
$var = preg_match ( '/[A-z0-9].*/' , $s , $m);
print_r($m);
```

In this case it will only fetch the data before a line break which is also compatible with Linux.

This, unless you use the multi-line modifier in regex. Then you can check if the `count($m)` is greater then 1 it means it has multiple matches.

The regex `[A-z0-9].*` means match in range of A-Z & a-z & 0-9. Cause regex runs on a lower level then PHP (on the CPU) it is much more efficient at this task.

Regex is like a search code for a string, its extremely flexible and I would suggest you dive into the subject.