# How to match letters, numbers and new lines with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this text file:

```
Host: x-sgdo40.serverip.co
Username: fastssh.com-test
Password: test
Port: 443
Info: Date Expired : 10-November-2016
```

I want to match that with letters, numbers, some additional characters and new lines:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 =.,:-]+$/",file_get_contents($filename))){
    echo "it matches";
}
else {
    echo "doesn't match";
}
```

The problem is that `/^[A-Za-z0-9 =.,:-]+$/` doesn't match new lines, how can I fix this ?

**EDIT:**

`^[A-Za-z0-9 =.,:\\n-]+$` still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex newline match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842404/regex-newline-match)

Comment: @mistermartin I know that post but adding `\n` in `/^[A-Za-z0-9 =.,:-\n]+$/` doesn't solve the problem

Comment: you didn't read the answer correctly. You need to escape it: `\\n`

Comment: @mistermartin `^[A-Za-z0-9 =.,:\\n-]+$` still doesn't work, please  try it yourself at https://regex101.com/

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9=.,:\s-]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9=.,:\s-]+$
```

- `\s` matches all whitespaces including newline
- Keep unescaped hyphen at first or last position in a character class

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dMZYWo/3)

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9=.,:\s-]+$/', file_get_contents($filename))) {
    echo "it matches";
}
else {
    echo "doesn't match";
}
```